# SMS Naive bayes with correct answer for training, correct and incorrect for testing

Tags: r

I'm trying to run Naive Bayes algorithm with 2 csv files one for training and the other for testing, the first file contain only one row which mean only one answer for training.

The first Data set for example:-

```
Answer
yes beacause of the average number of laureates per prize increased a prize may not be shared among more than three people

Evaluation
correct
```

Second Data set for example:-

```
Answer
1 yes, They can share the prize. If 2 people won the prize in the same fileds they shared it
2 No, beacause a prize increased substantially during The 20Th century
3 it may not be shared among more than three people, because the average number of laureates per prize increased substantially during the 20th century
4 No, Because the average number of laureates per prize increased substantially during the 20th century, if it shared the miximum is three people
5 yes because The Nobel prize is widely regarded as the most prestigious award available

Evaluation
correct
incorrect
correct
incorrect
correct
```

and here's the code

```
#importing the csv data
train_ds <- read.csv2("I:/Datasets/traindataset.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
test_ds <- read.csv2("I:/Datasets/dataset5.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#sms_raw 

#The type element is currently a character vector. Since this is a categorical variable, it would be better to convert it into a factor.
#Both numeric and character variables can be made into factors, but a factor's levels will always be character values. 

train_ds$Evaluation <- factor(train_ds$Evaluation)
train_ds$Evaluation
class(train_ds$Evaluation)

#Examining this with the str() and table()
str(train_ds$Evaluation)


#see how many are ham and spam
table(train_ds$Evaluation)


#install tm package

#install.packages("tm")


library(tm)

#create a source object from existing sms_raw$text vector, which can be supplied to VCorpus()

sms_corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(train_ds$Answer))# create the corpus - VCorpus(vecSource)
sms_corpus

#clean up our cropus using a series of transformations and save the result in a new object called corpus_clean
#standardize the messages to use only lowercase characters

# tm_map for an interface to apply transformations to corpora.

sms_corpus_clean <- tm_map(sms_corpus,
                           content_transformer(tolower))

sms_corpus_clean

#to check whether the command worked a advertised
as.character(sms_corpus[[1]])  ## Here will preent the first line in the dataset as it is 


as.character(sms_corpus_clean[[1]]) ## Each upercase characters convert to lowercase character of the first line 

#continue our cleanup be removing numbers from SMS messages
sms_corpus_clean <- tm_map(sms_corpus_clean, removeNumbers)

## as.character(sms_corpus_clean[[3]]) ## This is an example to remove numbers from text 
sms_corpus_clean

#remove any words thats in the stop word list
sms_corpus_clean <- tm_map(sms_corpus_clean,
                           removeWords, stopwords())
sms_corpus_clean

#eliminate any punctuation from the text messages
sms_corpus_clean <- tm_map(sms_corpus_clean, removePunctuation)
sms_corpus_clean






#create a custom function that replaces rather than removes punctuation characters
replacePunctuation <- function(x){
  gsub("[[:punct:]]+", " ", x)  ## gsub() function replaces all matches of a string
}
replacePunctuation

#install the package for the stemming functionality
#install.packages("SnowballC") ## Snowball stemmers packages are stemming algorithm for collapsing words to a common root to aid comparison of vocabulary.

library(SnowballC)


wordStem(c("learn", "learned", "learning", "learns")) ## This function computes the stems of each of the given words in the vector. This reduces a word to its base component


#apply the wordStem() function to an entire corpus of text documents
sms_corpus_clean <- tm_map(sms_corpus_clean, stemDocument)
##as.character(sms_corpus_clean[[5038]])
sms_corpus_clean

#the final step in our text clean up process is to remove the additional white spaces
sms_corpus_clean <- tm_map(sms_corpus_clean, stripWhitespace)
sms_corpus_clean
#sms message before and after clean up
as.character(sms_corpus[1:3])

as.character(sms_corpus_clean[1:3])

#creating DTM sparse matrix
#Constructs or coerces to a term-document matrix or a document-term matrix
sms_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(sms_corpus_clean)
sms_dtm
#create a DTM directly from the raw, unprocessed SMS corpus
sms_dtm2 <- DocumentTermMatrix(sms_corpus, control = list(tolower = TRUE,
                                                          removeNumbers = TRUE,
                                                          stopwords = TRUE,
                                                          removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                                          steming = TRUE
)
)
sms_dtm2


#comparing sms_dtm and sms_dtm2
sms_dtm

sms_dtm2

str(sms_dtm)


#creating training and test datasets
sms_dtm_train <- sms_dtm[1:1, ]
sms_dtm_train
sms_dtm_test<- sms_dtm[1:1, ]
sms_dtm_test

#creating the labels
sms_train_labels <- train_ds[1:1, ]$Evaluation
sms_train_labels
sms_test_labels <- test_ds[1:39, ]$Evaluation
sms_test_labels


########################################################3

#to confirm the subset are representative of the complete set of SMS data
#lets compare the proportion of spam in the training and test data frames:

prop.table(table(sms_train_labels))

#install word cloud package

#install.packages("wordcloud")

library(wordcloud)
library(RColorBrewer)

wordcloud(sms_corpus_clean, min.freq = 50, random.order = FALSE)


#lets use R's subset() function to take a subset of the sms_raw data by the SMS type.
spam <- subset(test_ds, Evaluation == "incorrect")
spam
#Next, we will do the same thing for the ham subset
ham <- subset(test_ds, Evaluation == "correct")
ham

#we will use the max.words parameter to look at the 40 most common words in each of the two sets

wordcloud(spam$Answer, max.words = 40, scale = c(3, 0.5))

wordcloud(ham$Answer, max.words = 40, scale = c(3, 0.5))


#display the words appearing at least five times in the sms_dtm_train matrix:
findFreqTerms(sms_dtm_train, 3)

#the result of the function is a character vector, so let's save our frequent words for later on:
sms_freq_words <- findFreqTerms(sms_dtm_train, 3)
sms_freq_words


#We now need to filter our DTM to include only the terms appearing in a specified vector
sms_dtm_freq_train <- sms_dtm_train[ , sms_freq_words]
sms_dtm_freq_train

sms_dtm_freq_test <- sms_dtm_test[ , sms_freq_words]
sms_dtm_freq_test

#To measure the number of times a word appears in a message, We need to change this to a categorical variable
#that simply indicates yes or no depending on whether the word appears at all

#The following defines convert_counts() function to convert counts to a Yes/No strings
convert_counts <- function(x) {
  x <- ifelse(x > 0, "Yes", "No")
}


#now we need to apply convert_counts() to each of the columns in oursparse matrix
sms_train <- apply(sms_dtm_freq_train, MARGIN = 2, convert_counts)
sms_train

sms_test <- apply(sms_dtm_test, MARGIN = 2, convert_counts)
sms_test



#install packages
#install.packages("e1071")

library(e1071)


#To build our model on the sms_train, we will use the following command
sms_classifier <- naiveBayes(train_ds, sms_train_labels)



#The predict() function is usedto make the predictions. We will store these in a vector named sms_test_pred. We will simply Supply the 
#function with the names of our classifier and test data set
sms_test_pred <- predict(sms_classifier, test_ds)
sms_test_pred

#compare prediction with true values

table(sms_test_labels, sms_test_pred)
```

when I'm trying to run this code I get 2 or 3 errors

> Error in apply(log(sapply(seq_along(attribs), function(v) { : dim(X)
>   must have a positive length
>        Error in table(sms_test_labels, sms_test_pred) : all arguments must have the same length

Comment: Hi M.Kar! Please have a look on how to produce a minimal reproducible example for R: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1842673
For example, we cannot see your data.